# css ie no-repeat bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, gwt

I have a textbox(A GWT-widget), that uses a png-background image to create rounded corners.
This works great in all browsers except ie(ie7 & ie8), where it repeats the image(even though I've used no-repeat), making the textbox look really ugly. Anyone encountered this problem before?

```
 @sprite .textBoxVerySmall
  {
gwt-image: 'textBoxVerySmall';
border:0 none;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
width:42px;
text-align:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
 }
```

Comment: what version of ie are we talking about?

Comment: I've seen the problem occur on ie7 & ie8

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stevelove.org/2009/07/10/png-background-repeat-bug-in-internet-explorer-7-and-8/

Comment: I tried switching the png image to gif's instead, but i still have the same problem:/

Comment: Try adding `zoom:1` to set hasLayout.

Comment: no luck with zoom either

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery UI it's as simple as adding the class "ui-corner-all" to the element you want to round.  No images to mess with, clean, and gracefully degrades on the "Evil browsers"

And, as a bonus, comes with amazing Calendar, Tab, Modal, and Tooltip widgets, just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was malformed html. I had not terminated div and block elements inside inline elements. When corrected, background were fine.

Check your html validity.